# Why does the brightness still automatically adjust after turning it off (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I turned off automatic brightness adjusting in the display preference pane (as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107692/screen-brightness-automatically-adjusting-in-os-x-mavericks)).  The brightness still adjusts automatically.  If I have the preference pane open I can even watch the slider moving to the right.  Is this a bug?  I would like to set the display to a lower brightness to save battery.

This is a Retina MBP from late 2013 with Mavericks.

Comment: Do you have Night Shift turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Normally if the preference settings do not obey your wishes means your user profile needs repair.

Try using different user to test.

Try the safe mode to test.

Reset your user profile ACL's

Comment: Hrgh... so Windows.  Should I reboot too, reinstall?